# AngularJS: Two-way data binding with matrix of text areas. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, matrix

I have a matrix which is basically an array of arrays of integers. Each element of that matrix is displayed on my HTML on a textarea.

The matrix looks like this

```
$scope.matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];
```

Somehow, I'm able to use this matrix like a proper 2 dimensional array. If I do a {{matrix[1][2]}}, the number 6 is correctly printed on screen.

The problem is, I want to bind the text-area onto each element of this matrix.

Javascript

```
var mainapp = angular.module("mainApp",[]);
mainapp.controller("mainController",function($scope){

$scope.matrix=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainController">


<span ng-repeat="row in matrix track by $index"><br>
  <span ng-repeat="element in row track by $index">
    <textarea "rows="1" cols="1">{{element}}</textarea>
  </span>
</span>
</div>
```

The matrix is displaying correctly as it should, with 2 rows and 4 colums of text areas.

Later on, I want to be able to perform various operations on this matrix such as finding determinants, multiplication and so on. Changes on these text-areas should automatically reflect changes in the matrix. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you not just do `<textarea ng-model="element" />`?

Comment: I tried and it works. So how do I access it? $scope.element?

Comment: Each textarea would update the corresponding value in `$scope.matrix` that it is bound to. Is that what you want? To update the original values in the matrix with new values from the textareas?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want.

Comment: `ng-model="element"` would not work "two-way" because matrix elements are primitive values, use `ng-model="row[$index]"` it will work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most conventional way of achieving two-way binding on each element would be adding an `ng-model` to your textarea that matches the particular index. it would look like so:

```
<textarea ng-model="matrix[$parent.$index][$index]" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
```

If you change a value from your controller it will be reflected in your view and vice-versa.

[Here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VhmtiAjr5AxihIobPQgn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your matrix as arrays of objects instead of primitives (ints).

```
$scope.matrix=[
  [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}],
  [{value: 4}, {value: 5}, {value: 6}],
  [{value: 7}, {value: 8}, {value: 9}]
];
```

Doing this will enable two-way binding.  If you don't do it this way, you may run into other scope-related problems down the road (if you use the matrix in a directive, for example).

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kuCExUl5Ujq9Jl1WreSo?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, I realized this when I started performing operations on the element. Apparently the text I enter through the text area is of type "string" while the remaining elements stay as number.

Comment: That's a separate issue.  You can deal with that by multiplying the value from the text area by 1 to force it to be treated as a number (this is demonstrated in the `sum()` function in my plunker).